# Out of Memory error while using here sdk

Tags: android, here-api

I am trying to use HERE Maps android SDK and testing on device operating on API 19(KitKat).  But I am getting out of memory error at startup. It starts with this error `E/dalvikvm-heap: Out of memory on a 262160-byte allocation.`and crashes by throwing exception as:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                
 java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:609)
     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:444)
     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2166)
     at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:710)
     at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable(ContextCompat.java:323)
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:202)
     at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable(AppCompatDrawableManager.java:192)
     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.getIcon(MenuItemImpl.java:421)
     at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.initialize(ActionMenuItemView.java:114)
     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.bindItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:206)
     at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.getItemView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:182)
     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.getItemView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:192)
     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.flagActionItems(ActionMenuPresenter.java:480)
     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.flagActionItems(MenuBuilder.java:1138)
     at android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(BaseMenuPresenter.java:91)
     at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter.updateMenuView(ActionMenuPresenter.java:229)
     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchPresenterUpdate(MenuBuilder.java:284)
     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.onItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1030)
     at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.startDispatchingItemsChanged(MenuBuilder.java:1053)
     at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:460)
     at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:61)
     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:559)
     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Its a bitmap issue it seems. But I am not loading any bitmaps.Now new exception is:`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
    at java.io.SerializationHandleMap.resizeArrays(SerializationHandleMap.java:48)
    at java.io.SerializationHandleMap.rehash(SerializationHandleMap.java:120)
    at java.io.SerializationHandleMap.put(SerializationHandleMap.java:104)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.registerObjectWritten(ObjectOutputStream.java:493)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1649)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1459)
    at java.util.Hashtable.writeObject(Hashtable.java:1079)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1031)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1382)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1649)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1495)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1459)
    at com.here.android.mpa.internal.cd.c(ObjectSerializer.java:45)
    at com.here.android.mpa.internal.cd.a(ObjectSerializer.java:22)
    at com.here.android.mpa.internal.cd$1.run(ObjectSerializer.java:97)
    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)`

Comment: Check image in drawable folder. Are those high resolution images?

Comment: @Piyush not high resolution I believe, two 36x36 pixels and one 96x96. It means issue is not on HERE maps side?

Comment: I have changed size of one image from 96x96 to 36x36. And now this exception is not thrown. But a new exception is thrown after the activity is recreated by unlocking a locked device.Please see my updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your **AndroidManifest** file under **application** tag use this

> android:largeHeap="true"

Comment: I have already used that option, but it didn't solved problem.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your app level gradel file

```
     dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
```

and add this line in your  defaultConfig

```
     multiDexEnabled true
```

Comment: multidex is not supported on API level 19(or less) isn't it? And I am not sure whether `javaMaxHeapSize "4g"` is supported on API 19(or less), does it support?